# What's the difference between using an intermediate variable and not?

Tags: rust

I am trying to code a doubly linked list with Rust. The main two types are defined as:

```rust
struct IntList {
    head: *mut Node,
    tail: *mut Node,
    size: usize,
}

#[derive(Copy)]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node {
    data: i32,
    prev: *mut Node,
    next: *mut Node,
}
```

I used 2 util functions:

```rust
pub unsafe fn raw_into_box<T>(raw: *mut T) -> Box<T> {
    mem::transmute(raw)
}

pub fn box_into_raw<T>(b: Box<T>) -> *mut T {
    unsafe { mem::transmute(b) }
}
```

And, I want to create a insert method to the list type:

```rust
impl IntList {
    fn new() -> Self {
        IntList {
            head: ptr::null_mut(),
            tail: ptr::null_mut(),
            size: 0,
        }
    }

    unsafe fn add_last(&mut self, v: i32) {
        let node = Node { data: v, prev: self.tail, next: ptr::null_mut() };
        let raw = box_into_raw(Box::new(node));
        let node = *raw;
        match self.size {
            0 => {
                self.head = raw;
                self.tail = raw;
            }
            _ => unsafe {
                // let mut last = *self.tail; // Notice here
                // last.next = raw;
                // not work
                self.tail = raw;
            }
        }
        self.size += 1;
        println!("added:{}", node);
    }
// ...
```

Behold, the lines commented don't work as expected. The elements in list will be only one-sized. I changed them, however, like this:

```rust
(*self.tail).next = raw;
```

the result will be correct.

---

So my question is, what's the difference between the dichotomy:

```rust
(*self.tail).next = raw;
```

vs

```rust
let mut last = *self.tail;
last.next = raw;
```

The former works but the latter not. Why can't I use an intermediate object?

Comment: Why the C++ tag?

Comment: In the latter example you're reading a copy of the `Node` from `self.tail` into `last`, which is then dropped when it goes out of scope.  I would ***strongly*** encourage you to avoid raw pointers and `unsafe` code here until you really know what you're doing.

Comment: You might be interested in [`Box::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) and [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak), which do what your helper functions do, but without `unsafe` when it's not needed.

Comment: @eggyal thx, i will. So variable assignment will consume the object?

Comment: You can take a reference instead: `let last = &mut *self.tail;`.  But really this whole thing can be done without any raw pointers or unsafe code so, again, I ***strongly*** encourage you to do that.

Comment: @eggyal Whah, just with this subtle modification, everything back to good. Nice of you! Besides, when you say "can be done without", you mean using `Option` or sth?

Comment: Mandatory reading if you want to do linked lists in Rust: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: Are you a beginner in Rust? Beginners should not try to implement linked lists in Rust, and especially shouldn't mess with unsafe code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider your statement `let mut last = *self.tail;`.  As The Rust Reference documents under [`let` statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#let-statements):

> A *`let` statement* introduces a new set of [variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/variables.html), given by a [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html).

Your pattern, `mut last`, matches the grammar of an [Identifier pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns), about which The Rust Reference documents:

> By default, identifier patterns bind a variable to a copy of or move from the matched value depending on whether the matched value implements [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#copy). This can be changed to bind to a reference by using the `ref` keyword, or to a mutable reference using `ref mut`.

In your case, the matched value `*self.tail` is of type `Node` which does indeed implement `Copy`, so a variable represented by the `last` identifier is bound to a *copy* of that `Node`.  You then mutate that copy, after which it is dropped when `last` goes out of scope; the memory in `*self.tail` is left unchanged.

To bind by reference instead, which will accomplish what you had intended, you can explicitly use a `ref mut` binding as mentioned in the quote above:

```rust
let ref mut last = *self.tail;
```

However, The Rust Reference goes on to document under [Binding modes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#binding-modes):

> To service better ergonomics, patterns operate in different *binding modes* in order to make it easier to bind references to values. When a reference value is matched by a non-reference pattern, it will be automatically treated as a `ref` or `ref mut` binding.

Thus you can alternatively still use a non-reference pattern by matching against a reference to `*self.tail`:

```rust
let last = &mut *self.tail;
```

In both cases, what's happening is somewhat more obvious if you consider the type of `last`: in your original attempt, `last` was of type `Node` whereas in both of the above it is of type `&mut Node`.

---

That all said, it probably isn't necessary to use raw pointers and `unsafe` code here at all (and I would ***strongly*** encourage you not do so).  For example, you could do something along the following lines:

```rust
use std::{cell::{Cell, RefCell}, rc::Rc};

struct IntList {
    head: Option<Rc<Node>>,
    tail: Option<Rc<Node>>,
    size: usize,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node {
    data: Cell<i32>,
    prev: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node>>>,
    next: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node>>>,
}

impl IntList {
    fn new() -> Self {
        IntList {
            head: None,
            tail: None,
            size: 0,
        }
    }

    fn add_last(&mut self, v: i32) {
        let prev = RefCell::new(self.tail.take());
        let next = RefCell::new(None);
        let node = self.tail.insert(Rc::new(Node { data: Cell::new(v), prev, next }));
        if self.size == 0 {
            self.head = Some(Rc::clone(node));
        }
        self.size += 1;
        println!("added:{node}");
    }
}
```

Admittedly, this does add the fairly trivial costs of storing and updating reference counts and runtime borrow-checks which a raw-pointer based version need not.  However, even if you want to avoid that, why reinvent the wheel when the standard library gives you [`std::collections::LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) ("*A doubly-linked list with owned nodes*")?  In any case though, note what it says:

> NOTE: It is almost always better to use [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) or [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) because array-based containers are generally faster, more memory efficient, and make better use of CPU cache.